# Combining dative and genitive

Tags: dative, genitive

There is this sentence in an old [episode page of Sturm der Liebe](https://www.daserste.de/unterhaltung/soaps-telenovelas/sturm-der-liebe/sendung/2007/folge-501-106.html):

> Bloßer Verrat würde ihrem ohnehin schon angekratzten Ruf nur schaden.
> Also ändert sie ihre Taktik.

The subject is a woman named Fiona. If I wanted to mention her name in the first sentence in place of `ihrem`, should it be as below?

> Bloßer Verrat würde **Fionas** ohnehin schon angekratzten Ruf nur schaden.
> Also ändert sie ihre Taktik.

It seems wrong as the `-em` ending and thus the dative is now lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dativ you lose is a possessive "article" which is dativ because of the noun it refers to.
However, you can express the same without an article - which you did with "Fionas".
You put it in front of the noun - despite it not being an article.  Since it is not an article and therefore also not an article with an ending, you use strong declension.
The adjective stays in Dativ, it just adapts to its surroundings.

a) Demonstrative pronoun in Genitiv. Strong declension:

> würde **deren** angekratzt**em** Ruf schaden.

b) Noun phrase in Genitiv. Strong declension:

> würde **Fionas** angekratzt**em** Ruf schaden.

c) Possessive "article" in Dativ. Weak declension:

> würde **ihr*em*** angekratzt**en** Ruf schaden.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's wrong. In this case the adjective has the *-em* ending and indicates the dative: "... würde Fionas angekratztem Ruf schaden".